# PyCharm: Can't find spark-submit

Tags: bash, pyspark, pycharm, conda, python-unittest

I am trying to run a test file in PyCharm with unittest.

It errors with this message:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit': 'myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit'`

I think it has something to do with my .bash_profile which a coworker helped configure. It looks like this:

```
export SPARK_HOME=myfolder/opt/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH
# added by Anaconda3 5.1.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Important to note, the path `myfolder/opt/spark/./bin/spark-submit` does not exist, but `myfolder/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit` does. I have no idea why the extra `./` is being added to the path.